# RestSharp trying to Deserialize Model with INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, rest, mvvm, model, restsharp

My model implements INotifyPropertyChanged, and because of that RestSharp can't deserialize correctly.

```
class SampleModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Int32 _sample;
    public Int32 sample
    {
        get { return _sample; }
        set
        {
            _sample = value;
            OnPorpertyChanged("sample"); // if I comment this line, everything occurs ok.
        }
    }
}
```

In my case I need to use the same class model in RestSharp request and MVVM. How can I fix it?

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: an obscure one, restsharp sends an Exception without any good information.

Comment: Catch it, call `ToString` on the exception object, and paste it into an [edit].